# MVC action with async and await

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I have the below action in MVC3 Application(empty application in VS2012) which just loads a Index page with just one H2 element. Granted this does not do anything but I am just learning the async and await functionality.

The index page does not load up. I just get this in the browser.

**System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]**

Also in fiddler i get the request in blue color.What Am i Doing wrong. Why is the view not showing up.

The asynchronous call does succeed and shows the html contents in the website.

View Code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            Task<string> getContentsTask = GetContentsAsync();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            string contents = await getContentsTask;
            return View("Index");
        }

        async Task<string> GetContentsAsync()
        {

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Task<string> contents = client.GetStringAsync("http://www.msdn.com");

            string data = await contents;
            return data;
        }
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Its mentioned in the question itself MVC4 though i dont use the webapi.

Comment: Are you sure? This would happen if you use an MVC version that does not recognize async.

Comment: @SLaks: Really Really sorry the app was an MVC3 one. I created one MVC4 and it worked fine. Thank you so much> Stupid accidental mistake on my side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC3 does not recognize `Task`s.

Upgrade to MVC4.